# Issue in displaying images

Tags: android, memory-management, android-widget

Description:

I am working on an application which includes displaying of images present on server. I am using grid view to display the images. Now as the images are in large amount. I am confuse whether first i should save the images on sqlite. 
How can i improve the performance of the application.

Comment: is your data coming from server side or its a local data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the images within the client side for better performance.

These links may help you, lets have a look..

[Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

[Android Imagedownloader project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/)